# HTML from Database to PDF

Tags: html, asp.net, export-to-pdf

I need to generate pdf from html dynamically using asp.net. HTML is stored in database. HTML has tables and css, upto 10 pages. I have tried `iTextSharp` by directly passing [html](http://hspinfo.wordpress.com/tag/convert-html-to-pdf-using-itextsharp/), it produces pdf which is not opening. Destination `pdf.codeplex.com` has no documentation, it produces PDF with styles from parent page.

Any other solution will be helpful.

Comment: [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) is a headless (no user itnerface) browser that will take a url, "screenshot" it and then save the result as a pdf. Copy it to your server and run it using `Process.Start()` or a similar mechanism

Answer (score 0):

I've tried many HTML to PDF solutions including iTextSharp, wkhtmltopdf and ABCpdf (paid)

I'm currently settled on [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) a headless, open-source, WebKit-based browser. It is scriptable with a [javascript API](http://phantomjs.org/api/) which is reasonably well documented.

The only disadvantage I found was that attempting to use `stdin` to pass HTML into the process was unsuccessful because the [REPL](http://phantomjs.org/repl.html) still has some bugs. I also found that using `stdout` seemed to be a lot slower than simply allowing the process to write to disk.

The code below avoids `stdin` and `stdout` by creating the javascript input as a temp file, executing PhantomJS, copying the output file to a `MemoryStream` and cleaning up the temporary files at the end.

```
    using System.IO;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Diagnostics;

    public Stream HTMLtoPDF (string html, Size pageSize) {

        string path = "C:\\dev\\";
        string inputFileName = "tmp.js";
        string outputFileName = "tmp.pdf";

        StringBuilder input = new StringBuilder();

        input.Append("var page = require('webpage').create();");
        input.Append(String.Format("page.viewportSize = {{ width: {0}, height: {1} }};", pageSize.Width, pageSize.Height));
        input.Append("page.paperSize = { format: 'Letter', orientation: 'portrait', margin: '1cm' };");
        input.Append("page.onLoadFinished = function() {");
        input.Append(String.Format("page.render('{0}');", outputFileName));
        input.Append("phantom.exit();");
        input.Append("};");

        // html is being passed into a string literal so make sure any double quotes are properly escaped
        input.Append("page.content = \"" + html.Replace("\"", "\\\"") + "\";");

        File.WriteAllText(path + inputFileName, input.ToString());


        Process p;
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();

        psi.FileName = path + "phantomjs.exe";
        psi.Arguments = inputFileName;
        psi.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(psi.FileName);
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        psi.CreateNoWindow = true;

        p = Process.Start(psi);
        p.WaitForExit(10000);


        Stream strOut = new MemoryStream();

        Stream fileStream = File.OpenRead(path + outputFileName);
        fileStream.CopyTo(strOut);
        fileStream.Close();

        strOut.Position = 0;

        File.Delete(path + inputFileName);
        File.Delete(path + outputFileName);

        return strOut;
    }
```